# Using standard initial jekyll set up, jekyll serve watch resulting in LoadError

Tags: ruby, jekyll

I've used the tutorial for Jekyll to set up a very basic blog and have hosted it on the localhost using `jekyll serve`, but when I use `jekyll serve --w`, the site generates then command gives

> C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:in 'require': 
>   cannot load such file --wdm (LoadError)

Followed by a lot of other information

I'm running Ruby 1.9.3 on Windows.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If it can't load `wdm`, I'd try:

```
gem install wdm
```

edit: Looks like [you're not alone](https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/issues/1699).  First Google hit.

Answer (score 2):

You need install wdm and directory_watcher:

```
gem install directory_watcher
gem install wdm
```

And remember add this line to Gemfile:

```
gem 'directory_watcher'
gem 'wdm'
```

Good luck!